# Cómo hago un <br/> con css?

Tags: html, css

Estoy haciendo un input con label y quiero hacer un "enter" entre ellos con css y no sé cómo hacerlo.

Este és el código:

```
<label for="input1">Tiempo</label>
<input type="text" id="input1">
```

Comment: ¿Por qué quieres hacerlo con `css`? ¿Qué te impide ponerlo directamente: **`<label for="input1">Tiempo</label> <br /> <input type="text" id="input1" />`**? Otra cosa es que quieras algo más que un simple `<br />`, como controlar el espacio de forma responsiva o algo así, en cuyo caso puedes hacerlo mediante `css` usando clases.

Comment: Intenta con `label::after{ content:"\a"; white-space: pre; }`.

Comment: @A.Cedano si, quiero controlar el espacio entre dos elementos, por eso hice esta pregunta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para agregar un salto de línea entre la etiqueta "label" y la entrada "input", puedes usar CSS para aplicar un margen inferior a la etiqueta "label". Aquí te muestro un ejemplo.

HTML:

```
<label for="input1">Tiempo</label>
<input type="text" id="input1">
```

CSS:

```
label {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

En este ejemplo, se agrega un margen inferior de 10 píxeles a la etiqueta `label`, lo que crea un espacio entre la etiqueta y la entrada. Puedes ajustar el valor del margen según tus necesidades.

Comment: Decir que esto se aplicará a todos los elementos `label` que haya en el documento.

Comment: Correcto, solo me he basado en el código que ha publicado el OP. En el caso de querer hacer ese salto de línea para ese componente en concreto, deberá poner algún identificador, por ejemplo `<label id="label1" for="input1">Tiempo</label>`

Answer (score 2):

El resultado de usar `<br />` es que genere un salto de línea entre los elementos:

```html
<label for="input1">Tiempo</label><br/>
<input type="text" id="input1">
```

Si quieres obtener este mismo resultado sin usar `<br />`, puedes hacer flexibles a estos elementos, encerrándolos en un `div` padre y que los elementos de adentro estén en columnas (uno debajo del otro), así:

```css
.elementos {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: min-content;
}
```

```html
<div class="elementos">
  <label for="input1">Tiempo</label>
  <input type="text" id="input1">
</div>
```

Y así puedes tener varios inputs, dando el mismo resultado como si tuvieran un salto de línea:

```css
.elementos {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: min-content;
}
```

```html
<div class="elementos">
  <label for="input1">Tiempo</label>
  <input type="text" id="input1">
  <label for="input2">Tiempo</label>
  <input type="text" id="input2">
  <label for="input3">Tiempo</label>
  <input type="text" id="input3">
  <label for="input4">Tiempo</label>
  <input type="text" id="input4">
</div>
```

Comment: Tu respuesta, al clicar en los `labels`, solo actúan sobre el primer `input`. Tendrías que poner `id` diferentes a cada uno de los `labels` con su correspondiente `input`

Answer (score 1):

Si no hay otro elemento en la misma línea que el `label`, puedes cambiar su propiedad de despliegue a bloque:

```
label{
  display:block
}
```

Si no es así, puedes usar el pseudoelemento `after` para insertar un retorno de línea:

```
label:after{
  content: "\A";
  white-space:pre
}
```

`\A` es la combinación de caracteres para retorno de línea, y `white-space: pre` hace que se le tome en cuenta como retorno.